# Visual Studio 2017 Tools for Apache Cordova - secure mode for remotebuild broken

Tags: visual-studio-cordova, visual-studio-2017

Ever since I installed `remotebuild` on my Mac I can't seem to use the secure mode. The documentation (https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/ios-guide/#remoteAgent) says that when I first run it - "The host name, port number, and security pin appear in the Terminal app." This did not happen for me, instead it showed:

> Warning: No server modules selected. Defaulting to configuration "modules": {"taco-remote": { "mountPath": "cordova"} }
>
> Remote build server listening on [http] port 3000
>   Please view/edit server configuration at /Users/[user name]/.taco_home/RemoteBuild.config. You many need to run 'remotebuild saveconfig' to generate it. You will have to restart the server if you update the server configurations.

So I thought I'd try regenerating the pin (as per https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/ios-guide/#securitypin) but when I ran the command `remotebuild certificates generate` I got the following error:

> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/remotebuild/node_modules/taco-utils/node_modules/applicationinsights/AutoCollection/Exceptions.js:25
>                       throw error;
>                       ^
>
> One or both of required CA files /Users/[user name]/.taco_home/remote-builds/certs/ca-key.pem and /Users/[user name]/.taco_home/remote-builds/certs/ca-cert.pem not found.

I've looked in finder and the folder 'certs' doesn't exist in the remote-builds folder, so no wonder it can't find those CA files.

Any suggestions?

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling `remotebuild` on the Mac but that's made no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Stop the remote agent on your Mac. Then, in a Terminal, execute the following command:

```
remotebuild certificates reset
```

Then, run this command:

```
remotebuild certificates generate
```

Doing this you will be able to see your remote config.

Reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/cross-platform/tools-for-cordova/first-steps/ios-guide#certificate

Answer (score 0):

Solutions:

1. You can simply reset the certificates and generate them again by issuing:

remotebuild certificates reset
remotebuild certificates generate

2. You can delete your existing RemoteBuild.config and run "remotebuild" again:

rm ~/.taco_home/RemoteBuild.config
remotebuild